# File Manager using Web.API and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my solution I have 2 projects. First is WebAPI, where I get classes: FileClass for files, DirectoryClass for Directories and ClassContext, that contains List of files and List of Directories.
In the HomeController I get method Get(string path) and it returns instance of ClassContext.
Then this data converts in JSON.
My second solition is simple Web Forms, where I use AngularJS to show these directories and files.
I have been trying a lot to get these data and for the moment directories and fils are being shown.

My question is: I want to click on directories, and then its subdirectories and files must be opened. How can I do this logic with AngularJS ?

Code of Controller of first project:

```
    public ClassContext Get(string path)
    {
        List<string> directories = new List<string>();
        List<string> files = new List<string>();

        db.Directories = new List<DirectoryClass>();
        db.Files = new List<FileClass>();

        // checks if path is empty
        if (path.IsEmpty())
        {
            directories.AddRange(Environment.GetLogicalDrives());

            for (var i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
            {
                string str = directories[i];

                DirectoryClass dir = new DirectoryClass()
                {
                    Name = str,
                    Path = str
                };

                db.Directories.Add(dir);
            }

            return db;
        }

        DriveInfo drives = new DriveInfo(path);

        // checks if the logical drive is ready
        if (!drives.IsReady)
        {
            path = String.Empty;
            return Get(path);
        }

        // checks if there is a file with such path
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            OpenFile(path);

            var lastIndex = path.LastIndexOf("\\");
            path = path.Substring(0, lastIndex);
        }

        directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path));

        // add directories
        for (var i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
        {
            string fullName = directories[i];
            var lastIndex = directories[i].LastIndexOf("\\");

            string name = fullName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);

            DirectoryClass dir = new DirectoryClass()
            {
                Name = name,
                Path = fullName
            };

            db.Directories.Add(dir);
        }            

        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path));

        // add files
        for (var i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            string fullName = files[i];
            var lastIndex = files[i].LastIndexOf("\\");

            string name = fullName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);

            FileClass file = new FileClass()
            {
                Name = name,
                Path = fullName
            };

            db.Files.Add(file);
        }

        return db;
    }
```

Code of View of Second project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="FilesController">
    <h3>Directories:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in result.Directories">
        <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
    </div>

    <h3>Files:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in result.Files">
        <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
</script>
<script>
myApp.controller("FilesController", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:55555/api/Home?path") .success(function(response) {
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to decipher what your json results look like but I think what you are trying to do is get a nested view of directories and files.  If that's the case then your html should look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="FilesController">
  <h3>Directories:</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in result.Directories">
    <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
    <h3>Files:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="file in item.Files">
      <a href="#">{{file.Name}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this is incorrect then please update your question with some sample json.

Comment: When I start the second project, I get such json:
{"Files":[],"Directories":[{"Name":"C:\\","Path":"C:\\"},{"Name":"D:\\","Path":"D:\\"}]}

I get 0 files and 2 logical drives. And I see them on my view.
I want to click on D:\, for example, and get all directories and files.

I did such project on ASP.NET MVC, but now I want to use Angular.

How must I get new directories and files and show them ??

Comment: So it doesn't sound like you're not getting the results from your api that you're expecting.  Correct?

Comment: I get disks C and D.

What must I add in my code to get next data ?
I click on D and nothing is happend.

Comment: Your question is really a C# question at this point not an angular question.  Angular isn't going to miraculously render data that's not in your json model that came from your api.  I would debug your api code and see why your not getting file names.  Also, your api should be returning a single object with files nested in directories rather than a separate directory and file object.

Comment: No, you didn't understand. I dont get files from this path,
because there are no files there.
If i write such path $http.get("http://localhost:55555/api/Home?path=D://Program files"), I will get directories and files.

My problem - I don't know, how to update data, when I open any directory. How to request my new path and get new directories and files ?

Comment: I resolved my problem. I added such code to view    
ng-click="GetNewData(item.Path)    and added such code in controller    $scope.GetNewData = function(path) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:55555/api/Home?path=" + path).success(function(response) {
                $scope.result = response;
            });
        }

And now it works.
Unfortunately web-service doesn't want to get access to different directories.